# If cell 1 or cell 2 is blank, then do this, else do this?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

What would be the eqivilant google sheets formula to execute this logic

```
if(typeof A2:A === 'undefined' || typeof B2:B === 'undefined') {
    return "--"
} else {
    return A2:A - B2:B
}
```

So basically if cell A or cell B is blank using something like `=ISBLANK(A2:A)` then return the string `"--"`, else return cell A minus cell B

This is what I tried with no luck.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2:A)|ISBLANK(B2:B), "--", A2:A-B2:B)
```

I noticed the `|` had no functionality, so I tried to use `=OR()` instead, but I couldn't use an else statement with `=OR()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A2:A="")+(B2:B=""), "--", A2:A-B2:B))
```

Comment: Will `""` count as an blank cell?

Comment: in 99% yes. but you can still use `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((ISBLANK(A2:A))+(ISBLANK(B2:B)), "--", A2:A-B2:B))` if you wish

Comment: Okay yeah it's working well. Thank you